# Pause when expanding split window with <c-w>_<c-w><bar>

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <Leader>m <c-w>_<c-w><bar>
```

It works as intended, making the current window (in a set of split windows) expand both vertically and horizontally.  The problem is that there is about a 1 second pause between the time I type `<leader>m` and the time the expansion takes place.

The reverse mapping, `nmap <Leader>M <c-w>=`, by contrast, works instantly.

How can I get rid of the pause?

Comment: Do you have another `<leader>m` mapping? Say `<leader>ma`…

Comment: that was my first thought, but i searched vimrc for `<leader>m` and only the two instance mentioned in my OP came up...

Comment: Do `:verbose nmap \m`.  Assuming `\ ` is your `<leader>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `:verbose nmap \m`. Assuming `\` is your`<leader>`. It will tell you map pings and the location the map was sourced.